# Azure App Service and WebJob not deployed to same resource group

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-resource-group

We have an ASP.NET MVC web site we are deploying to Azure within a resource group called "Production".  We have added a web job to that website and when we publish it is created and runs successfully but Scheduler is created in a new resource group called "CS-WebJobs-NorthEurope-scheduler".

Is there a way to get everything published to the same resource group?  I cannot find any documentation on specifying a resource group in the JSON configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your WebJob that's in a different Resource Group, but it's your Azure Scheduler job (which is set up to trigger the WebJob).

The suggestion is to avoid the use of the Azure Scheduler, and instead rely on the CRON support that is built directly into WebJobs. See [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON) for details.

Once you do that, you can safely delete your `CS-WebJobs-NorthEurope-scheduler` RG.